# I have an error when export a DOCX file to a PDF file, how can I fix it?

Tags: fonts, document

Bold, Italic,.. Unicode Text in a DOCX file gets an error when exported to PDF, example with bold text:

Text in docx file[image],

text in pdf file[image].

I tried to use many other applications to export that DOCX file to PDF but they still can't better.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate side effect of some languages that have a mix of character types. So when the font is subset some Latin ones will behave different to non Latin ones. This may be more noticeable when using Bold or Italic or Bold & Italic  ***IF the correct TTF font style file is not applied and embedded.***

Without your example it is hard to show exactly but here we see how it can happen.

In a PDF the characters you see on the screen are actually a mixture of numbers and some have familiar character shapes, so take this group
[image]

Here is how those glyphs are stored and presented in the PDF.

```
BT
/F0 36.0014 Tf
1 0 0 1 0 -29.9892 Tm
(M) Tj
/F1 36.0014 Tf
1 0 0 1 21.6009 -29.9892 Tm
<02f4> Tj
/F0 36.0014 Tf
1 0 0 1 43.2018 -29.9892 Tm
( ) Tj
/F1 36.0014 Tf
1 0 0 1 64.802707 -29.9892 Tm
<00fe02ba> Tj
/F0 36.0014 Tf
1 0 0 1 108.0044 -29.9892 Tm
(u) Tj
ET
```

[image]
Ignoring position and just looking at the letters we have

**/F0(M)/F1<02f4>/F0( )/F1<00fe02ba>/F0(u)**

Which means one font is used for the `M u` letters and another font for the `ởđấ` characters

Those Numbers are nothing whatsoever do do with real characters such as unicode they are simply an ID so the CID for `ở` is 02f4 and the CID for `đ` is 00fe etc so the letters need a lookup table to be converted into  Unicode characters.

The mapping from one to the other may be like this

```
/CMapName /GXUUYQ+Cousine def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
6 beginbfchar
<0003> <0020>
<0030> <004D>
<0058> <0075>
<00FE> <0111>
<02BA> <1EA5>
<02F4> <1EDF>
endbfchar
endcmap
```

We can now use that for Unicode Maping each letter in turn

```
<0003> <0020> = space bar
<0030> <004D> = M
<0058> <0075> = u
<00FE> <0111> = đ
<02BA> <1EA5> = ấ
<02F4> <1EDF> = ở
```

So if the font is corrupt by poor mapping or the wrong font stored in the PDF those numbers will get mixed up and the wrong letters applied.